# Can a Socket.IO client connect to SignalR server?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, signalr

Is it possible for a javascript client to establish a websocket connection using socket.IO to a SignalR .NET web service running on IIS?

Answer (score 7):

No it is not possible. They are using two different protocols to communicate . Both SignalR and socket.io sdks are a combinatin of server side library and a client side library .